# How to enable preTestConnection checkbox from deployment api for Websphere application server?

Tags: websphere-8, websphere-portal

I am trying to enable validate pooled connection checkbox for a datasource using deployment api.

```
AttributeList preTestConnections = new AttributeList();
preTestConnections.add(new Attribute("name", "preTestConnections"));
preTestConnections.add(new Attribute("type", "java.lang.Boolean"));
preTestConnections.add(new Attribute("value", String.valueOf(dsc.isvalidationOnMatchEnbled())));
configService.addElement(session, resourcePropertySet, "resourceProperties", preTestConnections, -1);`
```

When i do the able the pretestconnection is added to **custom properties** instead  **WebSphere Application Server data source properties** of datasource.

Please provide the attribute for preTestConnections.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in the admin console in the following panel:

Resources > DataSources > YOUR_DATASOURCE > WebSphere Application Server data source properties

Then, configure this set of properties how you desire:
[image: Screenshot of the Admin Console properties to set]

**The key here is that the property is called `testConnection` not `preTestConnections`**

You can also accomplish this using wsadmin scripting:

```
AdminConfig.modify(
  '(cells/myCell/nodes/myNode/server/server1|resources.xml#ConnectionPool_1)',
  '[[testConnectionInterval "0"] [testConnection "true"]]')
```

You can also accomplish this using the ConfigService API:

```
AttributeList preTestConnections = new AttributeList();
preTestConnections.add(new Attribute("name", "testConnection"));
preTestConnections.add(new Attribute("type", "java.lang.Boolean"));
preTestConnections.add(new Attribute("value", String.valueOf(dsc.isvalidationOnMatchEnbled())));

configService.addElement(session, resourcePropertySet, "resourceProperties", preTestConnections, -1);
```

Comment: Tried using test connection instead of preTestConnections. Still i got the properties into Data sources > TestDatasource> Custom properties. Can i have API to get list of Datasource properties.

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually through the Admin Console yet?  If you do the operation manually using the UI, you will be able to see what scripting gets generated for the corresponding interaction with the UI.

Comment: I have added that in admin console.

Comment: resources.xml script is effecting when i change validate existing pooled connection.      <connectionPool xmi:id="ConnectionPool_1450433030370" connectionTimeout="180" maxConnections="10" minConnections="1" reapTime="180" unusedTimeout="1800" agedTimeout="0" purgePolicy="EntirePool" numberOfSharedPoolPartitions="0" numberOfUnsharedPoolPartitions="0" numberOfFreePoolPartitions="0" freePoolDistributionTableSize="0" surgeThreshold="-1" surgeCreationInterval="0" testConnection="false" testConnectionInterval="0" stuckTimerTime="0" stuckTime="0" stuckThreshold="0"/>